# How to get certain column value from selected row to apply to filter?

Tags: vb.net

I'm a complete beginner in VB.NET
I have a task to make a form on visual studio and part of it is to make a functional button for report on orders. On navgrid portion of the form I have *master object orders* list with `order id` and `order date` while in datagridview a child object `orderslist` with details about the order

[image]

I need a button that would give me a report on selected order. 
I have made a report already and the code for button so far looks like this:

```
Private Sub BarButtonItem1_ItemClick_1(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles BarButtonItem1.ItemClick

    CR3.OpenReport("arpt_Sales_Orders", "FilterHere")

End Sub
```

if the `FilterHere` part is left empty, i get report on ALL the orders with their details.
I have been trying to look for how to filter out what i need but with little success. 
I have also tried to look into how to get value from order list (navgrid on the right) but I'm starting to think this is not gonna bring any use. Nevertheless here are my attempts at this so far

```
Dim vOrderID = atbv_Sales_Orders.CurrentRow(colOrderID)
Dim data As Object = NavGridView.SelectedRow(colOrderID);
```

Help would be appreciated. I've been on this for hours with little success

EDIT: 
To my understanding i need to add to filter section 
OrderID = (OrderID value from selected order)
So the question probably stands as, how do i get that value?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have finally found the answer myself. Posting it if someone would come across similiar issue. 
First row sets event to fire on pressing the button. Next two are what i needed

```
Private Sub BarButtonItem1_ItemClick_1(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles BarButtonItem1.ItemClick
    Dim vOrderID As Integer = CInt(cOrderID.Text)
    CR3.OpenReport("arpt_Sales_Orders", "OrderID = '" & vOrderID & "'")

End Sub
```

Works flawlessly for me